# Androi Studio doen't recognize key and value params from annotations

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations

I'm working with Spanneable strings from string resources, but when I try to get my key and value, the annotation doesn't recognize this one.

```
<string name="terms_conditions_prompt" formatted="true">Click to accept the <annotation action="openTC">terms and conditions</annotation></string>



val termsText = getText(R.string.terms_conditions_prompt) as SpannedString
val annotations = termsText.getSpans(0, termsText.length, Annotation::class.java)


val termsCopy = SpannableString(termsText)

for (annotation in annotations) {
    if (annotation.key == "action") {
        termsCopy.setSpan(
            createClickSpan(annotation.value),
            termsText.getSpanStart(annotation),
            termsText.getSpanEnd(annotation),
            SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
    }
}
```

[image: Image of my problem]

Comment: What do you mean by "the annotation doesn't recognize this one"? Is there a compile error? A runtime error? Undesired runtime behavior? And what information does the screenshot provide that isn't already in the code block above? Please update your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably just using wrong `Annotation` class import, that's why `key` and `value` attributes are not found, because imported class doesn't have these.

Make sure you are using `import android.text.Annotation`.